# Send form in email in ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, email

I want to send a form to users so that they can fill it in the email and just hit submit from there only. I just changed the form submission url ie:

```
 <%= simple_form_for @submission, :url => direct_submission_url( @submission.token) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :content, :label => "Your comments" %>
 <%= f.button :submit, 'Submit Report' %>
  <% end %>
```

Its not working. Its just redirect user to direct_submission_url( @submission.token) with a get request (without the form attributes) when submit clicked in the email form.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could try passing `:method => :post` alongside the url, though that should not be required normally. Is your `direct_submission` path matched with `post` in the routes?

Comment: I really don't think you should send the form itself via email. most clients would block the option to submit details directly from the email. do like the rest of the world and include a link that upon clicking opens your site with the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your routes you have to mention direction submission method as post ans in your form also you have to pass `:method => :post` and in direction submission method you have to render the new method after save.